# Multer Fileupload and entity too large

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

I m actually developping an application using express and multer and I m facing a problem with an "entity too large" error 413.

What I have tried :

```
app.use(BodyParser.json({limit: '500mb'}))
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '500mb', extended: false}))
app.use(multer({dest: './uploads', rename: rename, onFileUploadStart: onFileUploadStart, limits: {files: 1, fileSize: 500097152}}))
```

NB : my app is 9Mb large...

Can you help me ?

Comment: Do you use any proxy serverlike , nginx etc? ??